# Testing String pool

Tags: java, string, pool

I need to create a frequency table, that takes strings stored in an array or an `ArrayList`, and utilizes the `intern` method returning a String. I had hoped to do something like the following, but it didn't work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(myArray[i] == new String(myArray[i]).intern()) {
        myMap.put(myArray[i], myMap.get(myArray[i]) + 1);
    } else {
        myMap.put(myArray[i], 1);
    }
}
```

I acknowledge that there are better ways to create frequency tables, but the task constraints are binding.

**EDITED**

Ok, judging by the comments, this is not helpful. So lets back track.

I've imported the strings from text files, removed special characters, converted the text to lowercase, and then stored the individual words in an `ArrayList`. I've preserved duplicates of the same word because I'm trying to create a frequency table of the words. My task is to use the string intern method somewhere in my code to make this process faster!

As has been pointed out frequently on this forum, and every other resource I can find online, the string intern method can be used to test the equality of two string object references using the logical operator `“==”`. For example:

```
String s1 = new String("first").intern();
String s2 = "first";
String s3 = new String("first");

System.out.println(s1 == s2); //prints true
System.out.println(s2 == s3); //prints false
System.out.println(s1 == s3); //print false
```

But I'm dealing with ten's of thousands of words! How do I create a process that creates so many object references to an interned string, and then test each with the string pool so I know whether to increment the word frequency by one?

Comment: why do you want to use `intern()` method?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?  The only thing I see that could be a possible problem is when you are putting the data into the map that you are pullling with myMap.put(myArray[i], myMap.get(myArray[i])+1) the get is happening before the put so you may be returning a null on that call resulting in null + 1.

Comment: Use `myMap.containsKey(myArray[i])` instead of `myArray[i] == new String(myArray[i]).intern()` in if condition

Comment: Why are you doing `new String(myArray[i]).intern()` and not just `myArray[i].intern()`?

Comment: Before going down the *intern* path, You need to consider the JRE you would be using in your production environment.

Comment: By using `new String()` you bypass the interning, so your code will create 2 new objects if the String hadn't been seen before, or 1 otherwise. This code makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have commented, this is not the approach you would want to take in a production system. Having said that, the reason it isn't behaving as expected is because you  don't intern when putting myarray[i] into the map, so it  won't match the interned string on subsequent iterations.